# Where would be the best place to set up a government building in a world that constantly had earthquakes?

Tags: dystopia, natural

so I’m trying to figure out where a government would set up their main base in a world where earthquakes and natural disasters are imminent and happening all the time. I want it to be iconic like in the Eiffel Tower or somewhere like that but I don’t know if that’s structurally secure?

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are these earthquakes uniformly distributed in both geography and severity due to some mechanism? Or, like Earth, are there places that are more/less prone to quakes and damage?

Comment: Hi @SophieParsons, welcome.. could you please put in some more details ? How heavy are these earthquakes ? Is it a magnitude 4-5, or are we talking magnitude 7-8.. Is it daily, or weekly..

Comment: Hi, so I'm not sure on the magnitude but these earthquakes are so destructive that people are having to migrate to safer areas where there are less/no earthquakes. Think Geostorm and the intensity of those natural disasters. And they are definitely stronger and more frequent in certain areas, like where there is more tectonic plate activity (I don't know if that's the correct term or not)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make them floating structures in large lakes.

Depending on the level of technology, if its present day or near future, you can build large structures in a location, such as Lake Michigan, maybe a few hundred meters off shore. These buildings can be accessed by some means of ferry or cable car or other non-rigid access. this can act as protection from the earthquakes and also add a level of security for the government structures.

The water in which it floats on can act as a shock absorber from the tremors in the ground and, being a relatively small body of water, wont be susceptible to large tsunamis that would be generated by undersea earthquakes.

Comment: Watching the videos of small bodies of water sloshing back and forth in an earthquake doesn't give me much confidence in this answer. Since water is not very compressible, it is not a shock absorber. Small bodies of water simply transmit the earth waves to whatever is on them. Large bodies of water simply radiate the shock which diminishes them. Landslides have produced large tsunami in small bodies of water.

Comment: Earthquakes are also the cause of tsunamis, since an earthquake is just a pressure wave created by sliding tectonic plates. The pressure wave also moves mich quicker in water because of the increase in denaity of the fluid over air.  However, under the water at sufficient depth, earthquake effects could be reduced. Deep underwater structures that float freely from anchor points may survive

Answer (score 7):

If earthquakes are ubiquitous, and so the answer isn't the obvious: wherever the earthquakes are less severe - then the earthquakes aren't a factor in the where of the question, and it boils down to the same calculus for existing seats of government.

What would change, instead, is how the building would be constructed and what would socially be considered architecturally audacious. You wouldn't make it of stone/brick, you wouldn't build it extremely tall - but you could still build it taller than most of the rest of the building stock.

Remember that what's considered 'iconic' is a function of the context.  Since everyone else is also building under these conditions, there's probably not much in the way of altitude in the building stock to begin with so even a modest (by our standards) four storey deal would blow people's minds if it managed to stay standing.

Metal is a reasonable building material (to a point).  You'll want to check out stuff like [This article on quake-proofing buildings](https://www.bigrentz.com/blog/earthquake-proof-buildings). What makes buildings stand out is the advanced nature of the techniques, or the artistic flair of the architecture, or their cultural significance/history - not their geography or geometry (per se).

Comment: As additional info, Japan is in a highly seismically active region, [they still have skyscrapers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tallest_structures_in_Japan)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi "Seismically active" (California is this, too) and "are imminent and happening all the time" are different terms. "Seismically active" means "can experience an earthquake." "imminent and happening all the time" means "it's an earthquake, must be Tuesday."

Comment: Since "worst case scenario" is usually covered with a safety factor, the fact that lower intensity quakes happen all the time should _not_ count, should it? E.g. [Tokyo tower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Tower) is still up since 1958.

Comment: I'm not a materials/structural engineer, so I can't say for sure.  BUT: If it's seismically active to the point of noticeable earthquakes, I don't feel like 'lower intensity quakes' meets the OP's description - but I'll leave that determination to them.  It is certainly also true that constant, low-level stress inflicts wear and tear in ways that occasional small shocks do not.  But the maths for all that is VERY in the weeds.

Comment: 'lower intensity quakes' should have been 'lower _than the designed maximal quake intensity_'. Usually, if a building is designed for 8 Richter, it is guaranteed to withstand 8 Richter with a safety factor. A 7 Richter should not count. Now, considering wear, nothing is forever - structural engineering take the expected lifetime of a building in consideration when it comes to [the choice of materials, shapes and their already known fatigue behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatigue_(material)#Stress-life_(S-N)_method). I mean, I _assume_ they do...

Comment: Such assumptions are often perilous.. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silver_Bridge)

Comment: From the cited "In comparison, the Brooklyn Bridge, with wire-cable suspension, was designed with an excess strength factor of six." Which, to me, says that it is possible for structural engineering take them into consideration and those designing "in a world where earthquakes and natural disasters are imminent and happening all the time" can design an "iconic" structure "that’s structurally secure".

Answer (score 1):

## Orbiting the planet

Assuming this is a colonization of a new world story, the main HQ in this case might well remain off world. This would allow monitoring and response to any point on the ground and isolate from effects of any natural disaster arising from the planet. It satisfies your “iconic” requirement by literally being a beacon of hope in the sky as it orbits the planet.

Answer (score 1):

Building for an earthquake prone area requires two radically different techniques: rigid structures, and highly loose structures. Most of the modern designs are about adding enough rigidity to the structure so that the walls don't collapse. (There are also motion dampers built into major structures to minimize the action of the quake.) The ancient technique in China was to build loose so that everything would rattle and then settle back down into the position that you wanted it to be in. But the brick minor walls would collapse and need to be rebuilt.

You also need to ask what kind of earthquake you are dealing with. For example, the ancient city of Mycenae was built on an earthquake fault that would periodically go up a big amount. When the earthquake hit, it destroyed the city. You need to ask what motion the ground will take when it moves. Putting a building right over the fault line will destroy the building if half the ground under it drops 10 feet. (The Berkeley stadium has the fault running through it and part of the stadium will move in the next quake.)

Better yet is to have a structure that can be built again in a short amount of time. Government that is flexible would be a real benefit to mankind.

Answer (score 0):

You could build the capitol and capital in a large floating island or a large fleet of ships or floating platforms in deep seas.

Earthquakes don't have much effect on the surfaces of deep bodies of water.  Tsunamies in deep water are very long and low and are much less noticeable that normal ocean waves.  It is only when they reach shallow water that they compress in length and build up in height.

And if the land on the planet was a bunch of low islands and undersea earthquakes were common enough and powerful enough, every shore would be hit by devastating tsunamies from distant earthquakes frequently.

On January 26, 1700, parts of the Japanese coast were struck by a tsunami despite the lack of an earthquake in the region.  Centuries later geologists learned that the tsunami was caused by an earthquake of the northwest coast of the USA, thousands of miles from Japan.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1700_Cascadia_earthquake

In a world of small, flat islands and very common earthqukes, the shores of the islands that are routinely devasted by tsunamis will be a significant percentage of the total land area.

If the islands are small and flat enough, and earthquakes and tsunamis frequent enough, all the communities may be built floating in deep water to avoid tsunamies.

I note that tall buildings built according to strong earthquake construciton codes can survive earthquakes better than older low buildings which were not built to earthquake codes and not retrofitted to comply with those codes.

Thus it may be perfectly possible to build very tall buildings that resist earthquake damage.

The Palace of the Parliament in Bucharest, Romania is 84 meters (276 feet) tall, and 240 meters (790 feet) by 270 meters (890 feet), and has a floor space of 365,000 square meters (3,970,000 square feet) and a volume of 2,550,000 cubic meters (90,000,000 cubic feet).

> The Palace of the Parliament is the heaviest building in the world, weighing about 4,098,500,000 kilograms (9.04 billion pounds; 4.10 million tonnes).[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1700_Cascadia_earthquake)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palace_of_the_Parliament

I am sure it would suffer only minor damage in small earthquakes, but I don't know if it was designed to withstand strong earthquakes.  I think a version of it would very impressive looking, especially if the artitecture was modified a bit.

Personally I think that the main government buildings of your planet could still be highly earthquake reistant if they looked like scaled up versions of some of the most beautiful buildings on Earth but were constructed to resist even the strongest earthquakes.

Thus I can imagine that the congress or parliament building or presidential palace might look like scaled up versions of the Gol Gumbaz https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gol_Gumbaz

or the Thirumalai Nayakkar Mahal at Madurai https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirumalai_Nayakkar_Mahal

or the Mysore palace https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mysore_Palace

or the Rashtrapati Bhavan https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashtrapati_Bhavan

or the Sacre-Coeur at Paris [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacr%C3%A9-C%C5%93ur,_Paris#:~:text=Sacr%C3%A9%2DC%C5%93ur%20Basilica%20is%20located,was%20designed%20by%20Paul%20Abadie.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sacr%C3%A9-C%C5%93ur,_Paris#:%7E:text=Sacr%C3%A9%2DC%C5%93ur%20Basilica%20is%20located,was%20designed%20by%20Paul%20Abadie.)

or the Royal Pavillion at Brighton https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_Pavilion

or the Basiica of San Vitale  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_of_San_Vitale

Or the Istana Negara https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Istana_Negara,_Jalan_Tuanku_Abdul_Halim

Or Spaceship Earth at Epcot https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaceship_Earth_(Epcot)

Or the Pantheon https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheon,_Rome

Or Hagia Sophia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagia_Sophia

Or the Selimiye Mosque  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selimiye_Mosque,_Edirne

Or the Taj Mahal https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taj_Mahal

Larger versions of those structures, with more rooms, constructed with strong earthquake resistance, might make very impressive and earthquakereistent government buildings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try salt flats near the center of tectonic plates. Earthquakes typically occur at fault lines, so away from them is safer.

Salt flats are immensely flat, such that you could build buildings on large rollers that would allow the building to move independently of the ground. The buildings would have to be fairly flexible (more like large vehicles than buildings) and have suspensions. Barring a fracture or something causing terrain level shift, this would stop the structure from being destroyed.